# Associations, jointable with three keys

Tags: hibernate, jpa, associations, hibernate-mapping

I have question:

Can I have joinTable with tree keys, like:

```
User_UserDescription_UserReg_JOIN:

User_ID   
------------
UserDescription_ID 
--------------------
UserRegistration_ID
--------------------
```

And It will looks like this:

```
User_UserDescription_UserReg_JOIN:
  |   1  |     2    |      3      |
```

Is a possible to have jointable like this?? What should I do, asking for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short answer as you did not provide any @Entities : use @EmbeddedId

ex :

```
@Embeddable
public class UserDescRegId {
  private Long userId;
  private Long userDescriptionId;
  private Long userRegId;
  //TODO add getters,setters, constructor, equals, hasCode...
}

@Entity
public class UserDescReg {
  private UserDescRegId id = new UserDescRegId();
  private Description description;
  private Registration reg;
  private User user;
  @EmbeddedId
  @AttributeOverrides( {
        @AttributeOverride(name = "user", column = @Column(name = "", nullable = false)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "description", column = @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "registration", column = @Column(name = "reg", nullable = false)) })
  //TODO complete @AttributeOverrive 
  public UserDescRegId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
  //TODO getters/setters,
 }
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for answered me. I have question: Why you didn't specified  @AttributeOverride(name="") everywhere. I'm seeing that user was specified in name parameter, what about other ones? Also the column=@Column(name="") got me confused. There is no user inside. Why? What is the trick you trying to do with User? I want User reference to specific Description and specific RegestrationDate? Why I do this< just because I don't want to  populate user inside database, I would prefer bound same values with new witch kust inserted. Thank you

Comment: Well that just a short example. I can't tell you what you should insert because you did not provide any entities (as you can see you your question is too ambiguous and has been downvoted). So check the JPA documentation to help you resolve the missing parts.

Comment: Edit : @AttributeOverrides has been modified due to some typos